Please add a Save action button below questions and answers after the other action buttons
Currently, it is rather cumbersome to save a post to a particular list, and to tell the truth the Saves icon is not really intuitive for new users (however, once you know what it is then you know what it is).
Would it be possible to add a Save button next to the "Share Edit Follow Flag" buttons underneath questions and answers?

After clicking this new Save button, I would expect the Save to dialog to appear directly to enable a user to choose a Saves list and save the post together with a private note. In this way, we can avoid using the toast that pops up at the top of the screen together with the Manage button.

Once saved, I would expect the Save button to change to Saved in: Needs Edit, for example:

Clicking on Saved in: Needs Edit should take you immediately to the Needs Edit Saves list, ideally scrolling to this particular post.
It would not be necessary to implement an extra way to remove a post from a Saves list as the current Saves icon would still work the same as today.
To be clear, I am not asking for the functionality of the current Saves icon to change in any way.
The following posts highlight the problems and headaches that the current method of saving causes us:
Make it flow smoothly to add a post to a specific saves list
Make clicking "manage" after saving a post auto-focus the list-selection dropdown
One particular answer to "Bookmarks have evolved into Saves"

I think it would be weird to have two buttons the save a post with. though I do also want to have an indication of which list something is in and an easier way to change it from the post page itself.

@starball The Saves icon at the top is certainly useful as it gives an indication to users that they have saved or not saved a particular post (similar to giving users information about voting of a post). However, I often read through a post and then decide whether I want to save it or not and then I have to scroll back up to the top (especially for long posts). So, I guess there is a justification for having the button under the post too.

@starball I don't see a problem with having two buttons doing almost the same thing. There are other places here where clicking (or selecting) two different places (buttons) on a page results in the same action. Though I agree this does not happen often.

The answer in the 3rd link also exists as a question of its own: See private notes on saved posts
